# Twitter Typeahead.js & Bloodhound Keeps Showing Same Results Regardless of Text Entered

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

No matter what I type into the text input field, when obtaining the data remotely, I get these same results each time and it won't filter as I type additional characters.

However, if I set a products variable and assign it the value of "rows": in the JSON response and then remove the remote and transform objects and replace them with local and assign it to the products variable, it works perfectly. (Working Local Example is Below)

**What am I doing wrong in the remote example?**

```js
/* Results & Sample Json Response Are Further Below */

var bloodhound = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace("name"),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    /* CORS Bypass */
    url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://redacted.com/api/read/items/",
    prepare: function(query, settings) {
      settings.type = "POST";
      settings.contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
      settings.data = {
        key: "redacted",
        token: "redacted"
      };
      return settings;
    },
    transform: function(products) {
      console.log(products.rows);
      return products.rows;
    }
  }
});

$(".typeahead").typeahead({
  hint: true,
  hightlight: true,
  minLength: 1
}, {
  name: "bloodhound",
  displayKey: "name",
  //display: "name",
  source: bloodhound.ttAdapter()
});

/* 
Query Results:

<div role="presentation" class="tt-dataset tt-dataset-bloodhound">
  <div role="option" id="tt-8cdec2fd-d242-c74e-4f3c-982e76ffde0f" class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"> 
    Module Bounce House 
  </div>
  <div role="option" id="tt-5ce5f7aa-f7e2-25e0-7926-b3c6fe7648fd" class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable"> 
    Bouncer Combo 
  </div>
  <div role="option" id="tt-64e5423c-4b2b-6e54-5c0b-d91037d9f8a7" class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable">
    Obstacle Course &amp; Double Lane Slide
  </div>
  <div role="option" id="tt-6ec75aee-ae9d-4d18-a539-5af70108e1a5" class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable">
    Generator
  </div>
  <div role="option" id="tt-535945ed-63fb-b82d-8d15-510020179e08" class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable">
    22ft Big Rainbow Water Slide
  </div>
</div>

*/

/* 
Sample JSON Response:
{
    "row_count": 80,
    "rows": [
        {
            "name": "Module Bounce House",
            "picture": "https://redacted.com/cp/upload/items/Bounce-House-_Rental.jpg",
            "id": "73915",
            "categoryid": "2681",
            "base_cost": "139",
            "modifiers": [],
            "profileid": "1258"
        },
        {
            "name": "Bouncer Combo",
            "picture": "https://redacted.com/cp/upload/items/bouncer_combo_rental.png",
            "id": "73996",
            "categoryid": "2681",
            "base_cost": "199",
            "modifiers": [],
            "profileid": "1258"
        },
        {
            "name": "Obstacle Course & Double Lane Slide",
            "picture": "https://redacted.com/cp/upload/items/obstacle_course_double_lane_slide_inflatable_game_rentals-min.png",
            "id": "74031",
            "categoryid": "2682",
            "base_cost": "375",
            "modifiers": [],
            "profileid": "1258"
        },
        {
            "name": "Generator",
            "picture": "https://redacted.com/cp/upload/items/generator.png",
            "id": "74045",
            "categoryid": "2693",
            "base_cost": " 65.00",
            "modifiers": [],
            "profileid": "1258"
        },
        {
            "name": "22ft Big Rainbow Water Slide",
            "picture": "https://redacted.com/cp/upload/items/rainbow_screamer_water_slide.png",
            "id": "74046",
            "categoryid": "2679",
            "base_cost": "269",
            "modifiers": [],
            "profileid": "1258"
        },
        {
            "name": "22ft Rainbow Water Slide w Slip n Slide ",
            "picture": "https://redacted.com/cp/upload/items/22ft_water_slide_w_slip_n_slide.png",
            "id": "74047",
            "categoryid": "2679",
            "base_cost": "329",
            "modifiers": [],
            "profileid": "1258"
        },
        {
            "name": "Lava Slip & Slide ",
            "picture": "https://redacted.com/cp/upload/items/Volcano_Slip_n_Slide.jpg",
            "id": "74048",
            "categoryid": "2679",
            "base_cost": "219",
            "modifiers": [],
            "profileid": "1258"
        },
        {
            "name": "14ft Double Lane Water Slide",
            "picture": "https://redacted.com/cp/upload/items/14ft_double_lane_water_slide_with_pool.png",
            "id": "74051",
            "categoryid": "2679",
            "base_cost": "219",
            "modifiers": [],
            "profileid": "1258"
        },
        {
            "name": "18ft Big Rainbow Water Slide ",
            "picture": "https://redacted.com/cp/upload/items/18ft_rainbow_slide.png",
            "id": "74052",
            "categoryid": "2679",
            "base_cost": "235",
            "modifiers": [],
            "profileid": "1258"
        },
        {
            "name": "Caution Bounce House",
            "picture": "https://redacted.com/cp/upload/items/14ft_caustic_bouncy_jumper.png",
            "id": "74147",
            "categoryid": "2681",
            "base_cost": "139",
            "modifiers": [],
            "profileid": "1258"
        }
    ],
    "status": "Success",
    "elapsed": "0.01"
}
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/corejs-typeahead/1.2.1/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text">
</div>
```

A Working Local Example

```js
var products = [{
    "name": "Module Bounce House",
    "picture": "https://redacted.com/cp/upload/items/Bounce-House-_Rental.jpg",
    "id": "73915",
    "categoryid": "2681",
    "base_cost": "139",
    "modifiers": [],
    "profileid": "1258"
  },
  {
    "name": "Bouncer Combo",
    "picture": "https://redacted.com/cp/upload/items/bouncer_combo_rental.png",
    "id": "73996",
    "categoryid": "2681",
    "base_cost": "199",
    "modifiers": [],
    "profileid": "1258"
  },
  {
    "name": "Obstacle Course & Double Lane Slide",
    "picture": "https://redacted.com/cp/upload/items/obstacle_course_double_lane_slide_inflatable_game_rentals-min.png",
    "id": "74031",
    "categoryid": "2682",
    "base_cost": "375",
    "modifiers": [],
    "profileid": "1258"
  },
  {
    "name": "Generator",
    "picture": "https://redacted.com/cp/upload/items/generator.png",
    "id": "74045",
    "categoryid": "2693",
    "base_cost": " 65.00",
    "modifiers": [],
    "profileid": "1258"
  },
  {
    "name": "22ft Big Rainbow Water Slide",
    "picture": "https://redacted.com/cp/upload/items/rainbow_screamer_water_slide.png",
    "id": "74046",
    "categoryid": "2679",
    "base_cost": "269",
    "modifiers": [],
    "profileid": "1258"
  },
  {
    "name": "22ft Rainbow Water Slide w Slip n Slide ",
    "picture": "https://redacted.com/cp/upload/items/22ft_water_slide_w_slip_n_slide.png",
    "id": "74047",
    "categoryid": "2679",
    "base_cost": "329",
    "modifiers": [],
    "profileid": "1258"
  },
  {
    "name": "Lava Slip & Slide ",
    "picture": "https://redacted.com/cp/upload/items/Volcano_Slip_n_Slide.jpg",
    "id": "74048",
    "categoryid": "2679",
    "base_cost": "219",
    "modifiers": [],
    "profileid": "1258"
  },
  {
    "name": "14ft Double Lane Water Slide",
    "picture": "https://redacted.com/cp/upload/items/14ft_double_lane_water_slide_with_pool.png",
    "id": "74051",
    "categoryid": "2679",
    "base_cost": "219",
    "modifiers": [],
    "profileid": "1258"
  },
  {
    "name": "18ft Big Rainbow Water Slide ",
    "picture": "https://redacted.com/cp/upload/items/18ft_rainbow_slide.png",
    "id": "74052",
    "categoryid": "2679",
    "base_cost": "235",
    "modifiers": [],
    "profileid": "1258"
  },
  {
    "name": "Caution Bounce House",
    "picture": "https://redacted.com/cp/upload/items/14ft_caustic_bouncy_jumper.png",
    "id": "74147",
    "categoryid": "2681",
    "base_cost": "139",
    "modifiers": [],
    "profileid": "1258"
  }
];

var bloodhound = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace("name"),
  /*datumTokenizer: function(d) {
    Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace(d.name)
  },*/
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: products
});

$(".typeahead").typeahead({
  hint: true,
  hightlight: true,
  minLength: 1
}, {
  name: "bloodhound",
  displayKey: "name",
  //display: "name",
  source: bloodhound.ttAdapter()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/corejs-typeahead/1.2.1/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <input class="typeahead" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: when you were using remote mode , did you filter the data in your backend server code based on URL query parameter before you return them back to client?

Comment: @mohamed sulibi, there is no option to filter the results remotely, this API is very limited and will only allow me to retrieve all results. It has no options for queries. But if I feed bloodhound the same JSON data that local does then shouldn't it filter it the same?

Comment: I think it is your responsibilities to filter and process your data in server side before sending to client. The client should receive filtered records only, for this reason the search text was sent with the url %query% to let your server filter and fetch needed record only.

Comment: I don't understand why it would work with the same data locally and not with remote data though, that doesn't make sense to me. Shouldn't it provide the same functionality regardless of where the data is being obtained from? Whatever the code is for filtering the local data should also exist for the remote data.

Comment: It worked for me if we use `prefetch` instead of using `remote`